# Função randint não retorna um valor

Tags: python

Eu queria fazer o randint chamar um número aleatório, guardar o valor desse número, abrir uma pergunta pro usuário e se; a resposta do usuário for igual o número, dizer que ele acertou, se for diferente, dizer que ele errou. Porém, no código que fiz está sempre dizendo que está errado. segue o código

```
def adivinharnumero():
  from random import randint
  numeroaleatorio=randint(0,1)
  print(numeroaleatorio)
  resposta=input("Adivinhe o valor aleatório")
  print(resposta)
  print(numeroaleatorio)
  if resposta==numeroaleatorio:
    print("parabéns, você acertou!!!")
  if resposta!=numeroaleatorio:
    print("você errou")

adivinharnumero()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo por conta dos tipos das variáveis `numeroaleatorio` e `resposta`.

Quando você solicita o número ao usuário, você usa a função `input`, que retorna uma string, porém você compara com o retorno da função `randint`, que retorna um inteiro... Logo esses dados sempre serão diferentes.

---

Você pode corrigir de forma bem simples, convertendo o valor informado pelo usuário para inteiro, utilizando a função `int`:

```
resposta = int(input("Adivinhe o valor aleatório: "))
```

---

Também é possível fazer o inverso, transformar o valor retornado pelo `randint` em uma string, usando a função `str`:

```
numeroaleatorio = str(randint(0,1))
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: Valew cara! Você é fera!!!!!